# What will be the mathematical formula to fetch the position of a letter from this string?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

[image]

The above full string is a combined form of two different strings named string-1 and string-2. Both strings has equal length of 32 characters. There is two other parameters **interval** and **size**. string-1 is broken into pieces of length = **interval** and string-2 is broken into pieces of length = **size** to form the full string. once all the pieces of string -2 is put in full string, pieces of string-1 is padded to the full string.

possible values for **size** variable are : 2, 4, 8, 16
possible values for **interval** variable are : any value from 1 to value of **size** variable

My requirement is to write a mathematical equation fetch index(in full string) of nth number of character of string-1 without separating the full string into its 2 original strings.

for e.g.
In above full string, if I want to fetch 5th character of string-1 it will be **'2'** whose index in full string is **12**.
and for 6th character which is **'1'** has the index **15**.

P.S. index of the character is counted from 0 to **index**, and the nth character is counted from 1 to **n**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given character $n$ of string $1$, it will be in the $\lfloor \frac{n}{interval}\rfloor +1$ block.  The reason I used floor instead of ceiling (which would get rid of the $+1$) is that integer divide gives the floor.  There will be $(\lfloor \frac{n}{interval}\rfloor )size$ characters from string $2$ preceeding it, so it will be at position $(\lfloor \frac{n}{interval}\rfloor )size+n$ in the final string.  Note that you are inconsistent in the referencing-you talk about the $5$th character as $2$, but it is in position $4$ if you index from $0$ and that you say both strings will have $32$ characters in contrast to the example.  This will be correct as long as you don't run out of string $2$ characters.  If you use all the string $2$ characters, the position will be $n+32$ if string $2$ is $32$ characters long.

Comment: (⌊n/interval⌋)size+n  gives me the right character. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: In PHP i wrote : min(32,(floor($n/$interval)*$size))+$n  It handles both the cases.